# Interpreting vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vectors

Given that $x, y\in \mathbb R^m$, what exactly does the notation $\binom{x}{y}$
mean? If $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{bmatrix}, y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_m \end{bmatrix}$ then how can these vectors form elements within another vector? The two most likely interpretations I can think of would be
\begin{equation*}
\binom{x}{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_m \\
y_1 & \dots & y_m \end{bmatrix} \text{ or } 
\binom{x}{y} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & y_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x_m & y_m\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
And the third maybe
\begin{equation*} 
\binom{x}{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \\ y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_m\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Comment: The third is intended. We’re thinking of $\Bbb R^{m+m}$ as $\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: I also see the third as the intended meaning. I think of it as a variety of block matrix notation.

Comment: We often use the third one to denote $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 x\\
 y\\
\end{array} \right) $

Comment: Thanks everyone, that clears everything up. Is there a compact way of writing the third vector?